# How do I choose my static IP addresses

Tags: ubuntu, internet

I'm trying to set up a basic server that can be accessed on the WWW via a domain name. Using Ubuntu 12LTS Server and am stuck on Step 7 of this tutorial : [The Perfect Server - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS | HowtoForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-apache2-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p3)

> Because the Ubuntu installer has configured our system to get its
>   network settings via DHCP, we have to change that now because a server
>   should have a static IP address. Edit /etc/network/interfaces and
>   adjust it to your needs (in this example setup I will use the IP
>   address 192.168.0.100 and the DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

I've also read the manual entry on this, but I'm still confused. What are "my needs"? How did this author get those IP addresses? Should I just use those exact ones on my machine?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this server hosted somewhere, or should it get access to the network via the local lan?

Comment: Downvoted? Maybe let me know why so I can improve this question?

Comment: @ThomasBerger It would be a physical server sitting in my apartment.

Comment: Home networking questions are off-topic at Server Fault. If you really intend to host a server, you shouldn't do so at home for a variety of reasons (lack of a static IP address being just one).

Answer (score 3):

You need a static ip from your provider. If you have a consumer connection you probably only have a dynamic ip.

If you don't have a static ip for your internet connection you might want to take a look into [DynDNS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DynDNS).

Comment: I see, so DynDNS would create a static IP that reroutes to my provider's dynamic IP?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz No, DynDNS points a domain/subdomain at your current dynamic IP, and updates it when it changes.

Comment: Oh sweet, that's even better.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is connected to your home network, in the most cases you want to choose DHCP.

Your local router will assign a free IP to your server and also provides informations about DNS servers.

If there is no DHCP, you could choose a free IP address within your local network and assign this one to the server.

Anyway, you should learn more about IP addresses an networking first. Just ask google about these terms.